# need to simplify a complex date

Tags: r, date, text, simplification

I have about 200,000 records that have dates as text in this format:  Monday, March 01, 2018 and need to be converted to this format: 03-01-2018.  A solution using XL or R would work.  The key here is that the final text needs to be able to be used as a date for sorting and selecting.  I don't need the day of week info.

Thanks all !

Comment: Is XL a programming language? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out ...

test is a vector of dates in the form ... "Monday, March 01, 2018"

```r
test[grepl("[,.,]",test)] <- format(as.Date(test[grepl("[,.,]",test)],cur_date_form), des_date_form)
```

where `cur_date_form` is "%A, %B %d, %Y" and `des_date_form` is "%m-%d-%Y"

Comment: this looks reasonable, but it's not at all clear what the `grepl(...)` clauses are doing. As written I believe that these should select any element that contains a dot (`.`) or a comma ... ?